# How to format stored procedure to map on EF object and custom data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

How to bind the stored procedure to object which contains

```
public class Info
{
   public string PupilFirstName // (just a string),
   public string PupilLastName // (just a string)
   public Teacher Teacher // (EF object)
}
```

So my stored procedure is:

```
select Teacher.*, Pupil.FirstName PupilFirstName, Pupil.LastName PupilLastName 
from Pupil
join Teacher on Teacher.Id = Pupil.TeacherId
```

Though it doesn't work, probably I need to change stored procedure but I don't know how. Please help.

---

UPDATE:
Let me try to explain with more details:
I want that stored procedure will be bind on row with complex type and entity type, so the result will be: string, string, domain object.

Comment: Well what does the `Stored Procedure look like`

Comment: can you explain what doesn't work properly..? are you also missing perhaps a `Where` clause in that `JOIN Statement`? is this correct as well `public Teacher Teacher` can you not change the variable name to camel case or something? it would also help to know what the relationship is i.e `1:1` `0:1 ...etc`

Comment: the query is right, only the question about binding. Why when I put Teacher.* it doesn't bind to object, I think I am missing some syntax for binding.

Comment: perhaps you should Alias Teacher something like `Select Teacher.* T, Pupil.FirstName PupilFirstName, Pupil.LastName PupilLastName from Pupil p Join T.Teacher on T.Id = P.TeacherId`

Comment: I will try it now. Give me several minutes please.

Comment: I may not have the Aliasing correct fully because of how you have named `Teacher Teacher` in your public declaration can that be changed to something else to improve your own readability..?

Comment: no, this suggestion will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF doesn't support binding nested entities. It binds only single entity level. Also if you use `Info` as mapped complex object it cannot contain reference to entity - that is also not supported because complex object can be used as a member of entity but not vice-versa.

You need to flatten your `Info` (make it contain all members of `Teacher`) and your stored procedure must return columns with same names as properties in your `Info` class.